# Jquery Redirect to New Page after Pick Date

Tags: jquery

I just made a simple Jquery Date Picker . What i Just want is after i select a specific date ( Let's say 2014 / 05 / 03 ) then it should automatically redirect to new page . I was searching for this , But I couldn't find any Luck . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply trigger that event (e.g. by jQuery `.change()` method) and then call a redirect method:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

(like in [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)).

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#dateInput').change(function(){
     if(conditionMatches)
        window.location = "http://google.com";
});
```

You could even use datepicker's onSelect event

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function() { ... }
});
```